# How do I generate a new Error() with Mongoose that maintains the same nested structure as the standard Validation Error object?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, validation, mongoose, error-handling

## Question

How do I generate an error that is more easily iterable on the front-end from Mongoose, that maintains the standard Validation error structure using `new Error()`?

### Issue

I have a handful of validations that run on my Mongoose schema. I have a pre-save function that I'm using to encrypt a password using `bcrypt`. I'm trying to make sure I catch all promises, and I've got a situation where I may receive an error from bcrypt if a user's password is not successfully hashed. I'd like to generate a generic error that I can have display on the front-end. Right now I iterate through validation errors in the `error.errors` object which is returned from Mongoose in the following format:

```
// Schema
const MySchema = new Schema(
  {
    myField: {
      type: String,
      minlength: [3, "My Field must be 3-30 characters."],
      maxlength: [30, "My Field must be 3-30 characters."],
      required: [true, "My Field is required."],
      trim: true
    },
)

// Errors returned in the following format:

errors: {
  myField: {
    message: "Custom error warns foo must be bar."
  },
  // ... more error'd fields here
}
```

I'd like to add a custom error in the same format, so that the single `error.errors` object I'm sending back to my front-end in JSON format is easily iterable. Right now, I take my `bcrypt` error, and format my own object in this similar format, but it's not a very elegant way to do things.

I may be confused on how to properly use `New Error("My custom error here")` and may be making my validation harder than it needs to be, and would love any insight.

### Code

- You can see on [Line 88 in my User-model.js](https://github.com/twknab/gear_list_MEVN/blob/f9a8896a325cd4ad8274f0de0bfafb244849b491/server/src/models/User-model.js#L88) that I'm catching a bcrypt error and formatting an object that resembles the same hierarchy as the standard validation errors object (afore noted).
- I then send the `error.errors` object via JSON from the backend [Line 19 in user-controller.js](https://github.com/twknab/gear_list_MEVN/blob/f9a8896a325cd4ad8274f0de0bfafb244849b491/server/src/controllers/user-controller.js#L19) to the front-end for iteration.

Is there a cleaner way to utilize `New Error()` and make my error handling a bit nicer, without having to format my own error objects in this way?